# how to use .populate() in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, populate

I have a collection called

```
CR
```

what I want to do is query CR like so:

```
let cre = await CR.find({myid: "xxxxxx"})
```

and i also have a collection called `cla`, but that one i need to query based off of the results of `cre`. The results of cre will return a class_id, in which I need to use to query the `cla` collection to find the `_id`. At the end of all of this, I want to ideally merge the two, which I believe you can do through `.populate()`, and then send it to teh front-end as one.;

I have tried this:

```
 let cre = await cr.find({myid: "xxx"}).populate('loc').populate('desc').populate('dt');
```

but this isn't working. how can I fix this?

Comment: you could try breaking it up into separate calls with `await` at each.

Comment: @tromgy that didn't work either, unfortunatley

Answer (score 2):

It may be due to schemas, but this is how it's clean and simple to use;

```js
 let cre = await cr.find({myid: "xxx"}).populate(['loc','desc','dt']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can take **cla** collection "_id" in **CR** collection schema. In schema of **CR** collection refer to *cla model id* like this,

```
const creSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    classnId: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Cla" }
});
```

Then you can populate like,

```
const cres = await CR.find({}).populate({path:'classnId', select:'columnName'});
```

Hopefully, this will solve your issue.

Note: There in populating you can give multiple column names by space and if you give a minus before a column name like this (-columnName) then that column will not show when you will call the API.